# 5. c4 vs 5. Bd3 in the Tal variation of the Advance Caro Kann

Tags: opening, caro-kann

In the Tal variation of the Advance Caro Kann after

1. e4 c6
2. d4 d5
3. e5 Bf5
4. h4 h5

White has two main options, 5. c4 and 5. Bd3. What are the differences in the positions reached by each move in terms of the middle game plans and nature of said middle game?

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "8"]

1. e4 c6 
2. d4 d5 
3. e5 Bf5
4. h4 h5
5. c4
(5. Bd3)
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question

Comment: Related (not a dupe). For Black's plans, see [Black's tools in the Caro-Kann Advanced Tal Variation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/34644/26335)